# Merge an Update Query with a Select Query MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an update query which updates the StatusFK in the Order Table. And i have a Select query which displays the Order that has all of the OrderDetails with a status = 2 (Received)

I want to combine the 2 Queries so it finds the records to update and updates all found records all in one query? is this possible?

```
UPDATE tblOrder INNER JOIN tblOrderDetail ON tblOrder.OrderPK = tblOrderDetail.OrderFK 
SET tblOrder.Statusfk = 2
WHERE (((tblOrderDetail.OrderFK)=[forms]![frmReceive]![OrderPK]));
```

Find Orders that need receiving

```
SELECT tblOrder.OrderPK
FROM tblOrder
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT 1
FROM tblOrderDetail
WHERE tblOrderDetail.OrderFK = tblOrder.OrderPK
AND tblOrderDetail.StatusFK <> 2 AND tblOrder.StatusFK );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do it like this:

```
UPDATE tblOrder
    SET tblOrder.Statusfk = 2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM tblOrderDetail
                  WHERE tblOrderDetail.OrderFK = tblOrder.OrderPK AND
                        tblOrderDetail.StatusFK <> 2 AND
                        tblOrder.StatusFK
                 );
```